How to make the sun a light source in my solar system simulation program with pyopengl and pygame?
I wrote a Planet class and use draw_self function to render the sphere, but I didn't know where I should put the code about lighting.
I try to initial the light before the loop but the planets were not lit.I think maybe it is because I use textures?
I know little about pyopengl and I don't know if I need shaders.
Here is the code
import math

import numpy as np
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

from OpenGL.GL import *
from OpenGL.GLU import *

from PIL import Image

time_scale = 5

G = 12384548 * (time_scale ** 2)
AU = 5859375


def read_texture(planet_name):
    texture = glGenTextures(1)
    image = Image.open(f"resources/bmp/{planet_name}.bmp")

    ix = image.size[0]
    iy = image.size[1]
    image = image.tobytes("raw", "RGBX", 0, -1)
    # Create Texture
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture)  # 2d texture (x and y size)

    glPixelStorei(GL_UNPACK_ALIGNMENT, 1)
    glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 3, ix, iy, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, image)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_CLAMP)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL_REPEAT)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexParameterf(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST)
    glTexEnvf(GL_TEXTURE_ENV, GL_TEXTURE_ENV_MODE, GL_DECAL)
    return texture


class Planet:
    def __init__(self, planet_name, pos, radius, mass, speed=None):
        self.name = planet_name
        self.texture = read_texture(planet_name)
        self.pos = np.array(pos, dtype="float64") * AU
        self.radius = radius
        self.mass = mass
        self.speed = np.array(speed, dtype="float64") if speed else np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype="float64")
        self.speed *= time_scale

        self.sphere = gluNewQuadric()

    def draw_self(self):

        glPushMatrix()

        glTranslatef(*self.pos)
        glRotatef(90, 1, 0, 0)
        gluQuadricTexture(self.sphere, GL_TRUE)
        glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D)
        glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, self.texture)
        gluSphere(self.sphere, self.radius, 64, 64)  # Draw sphere

        glPopMatrix()

    def move(self):
        self.pos += self.speed

    def calc(self, mass2, distance):
        force = G * mass2 * self.mass / (np.linalg.norm(distance) ** 3) * distance
        self.speed += force / self.mass


pygame.init()

width, height = display = (1900, 1060)
scree = pygame.display.set_mode(display, DOUBLEBUF | OPENGL)


glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
gluPerspective(45, (display[0] / display[1]), 2, 1e20)

glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)

# here is the light part
light_position = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0]
light_ambient_color = [0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0]
light_diffuse_color = [1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]

glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_POSITION, light_position)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_AMBIENT, light_ambient_color)
glLightfv(GL_LIGHT0, GL_DIFFUSE, light_diffuse_color)
glEnable(GL_LIGHTING)
glEnable(GL_LIGHT0)
glColorMaterial(GL_FRONT, GL_DIFFUSE)
glEnable(GL_COLOR_MATERIAL)

glMatrixMode(GL_MODELVIEW)

pygame.mouse.set_visible(False)
pygame.event.set_grab(True)

sun = Planet("sun", (0, 0, 0), 109000, 330000)
mercury = Planet("mercury", (0, 0, -0.37), 575, 0.055, [-1373, 0, 0])
venus = Planet("venus", (0, 0, -0.72), 1423.5, 0.815, [-984, 0, 0])
earth = Planet("earth", (0, 0, -1), 1500, 1, [-835, 0, 0])
moon = Planet("moon", (0, 0, -1.00256), 409, 1 / 81, [-864, 0, 0])
mars = Planet("mars", (0, 0, -1.52), 798, 0.107, [-677, 0, 0])
jupiter = Planet("jupiter", (0, 0, -5.2), 16800, 317.8, [-366, 0, 0])

background = read_texture('venus')
ball = gluNewQuadric()


planets = [mercury, earth, moon, venus, mars, jupiter]

cam = np.array([0, 0, 0], dtype="float64")
target = np.array([0, 0, -1], dtype="float64")

gluLookAt(*cam, *(cam + target), 0, 1, 0)
viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)


camera_yaw = 180
camera_pitch = 0

step = 100

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

running = True
while running:
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT)  # Clear the screen

    glLoadIdentity()

    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                running = False
    
        elif event.type == pygame.MOUSEMOTION:
            dx, dy = pygame.mouse.get_rel()

            camera_yaw += dx * 0.1
            camera_pitch = min(max(camera_pitch - dy * 0.1, -89.9999), 89.9999)

    glPushMatrix()

    keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()

    if keys[pygame.K_w]:
        cam += (0, 0, -step)
    elif keys[pygame.K_s]:
        cam += (0, 0, step)
    if keys[pygame.K_a]:
        cam += (-step, 0, 0)
    elif keys[pygame.K_d]:
        cam += (step, 0, 0)
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        cam += (0, step, 0)
    elif keys[pygame.K_LSHIFT]:
        cam += (0, -step, 0)

    for i in planets:
        for j in planets:
            if i != j:
                i.calc(j.mass, j.pos - i.pos)

    for i in planets:
        i.move()

    ah, av = math.radians(camera_yaw), math.radians(camera_pitch)

    tmp = cam + earth.pos
    target = tmp + [math.sin(ah) * math.cos(av), math.sin(av), -math.cos(ah) * math.cos(av)]

    gluLookAt(*tmp, *target, 0, 1, 0)

    for i in planets:
        i.draw_self()

    glPopMatrix()

    glMultMatrixf(viewMatrix)
    viewMatrix = glGetFloatv(GL_MODELVIEW_MATRIX)

    pygame.display.flip()

    clock.tick(60)


